# Open shell in emacs with a given working directory

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet

I want to have a `make-shells` command in emacs that will open a number of emacs-shell buffers, each with its own working directory. The idea is that for each project I'm working on, I have a shell that starts out in that project's directory, so I can easily switch between them.

Currently I have this code:

```
(defun shell-dir (name dir)
  (interactive "sShell name: \nDDirectory: ")
  (shell name)
  (switch-to-buffer name)
  (comint-send-string (current-buffer) (concat "cd " dir "\r"))
  (sleep-for 0 10)
  (dirs))

(defun make-shells ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-dir "project1" "~/proj/project1")
  (shell-dir "project2" "~/proj/project2")
  (shell-dir "project3" "~/proj/project3")
  (delete-window))
```

This is pretty ugly, though, and half the time `(dirs)` doesn't pick up the correct path, so tab completion breaks until I re-run it manually. Is there a built-in way to set the current working directory of the emacs shell? Or would something like [CEDET](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) (plus less reliance on the shell vs. emacs modes) be a much better solution to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I experienced similar problems with the current directory tracking provided by Emacs, so I wrote one which solves the problem once and forever.

Check it out [here](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/08/emacs-tip-25-shell-dirtrack-by-prompt.html).

The short version of what it does is that you modify your shell prompt to include a full path to the current directory (only when running inside Emacs), and the Emacs shell buffer will use that.

This means you never have to do <kbd>M-x dirs</kbd> again.

There's also the package [`dirtrack`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellDirtrackByPrompt) (shipped with Emacs) which does the same thing.

I like my version better because it removes the path from the prompt.  I don't want to see the entire path in my prompt as my current directory is often very long.

Once you use one of the above two solutions, you can simplify your `shell-dir` routine to be:

```
(defun shell-dir (name dir)
  (interactive "sShell name: \nDDirectory: ")
  (let ((default-directory dir))
    (shell name)))
```

Answer (score 1):

One more answer... I found there was a way (on Linux) to make Emacs figure out the current directory properly, by using the /proc filesystem.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ShellDirtrackByProcfs

That way, you just have to start up the shell in whatever directory and Emacs will automatically figure it out and get the tab-completion etc. right.